# How to call function or module using Scala ScriptEngine

Tags: scala, scriptengine

How to call function or module using ScriptEngine.

here is my sample code , which is compiling fine , but at runtime its throwing exception  scalaVersion := "2.12.4" and sbt.version = 0.13.16, java is jdk1.8.0_131

```
import java.io.FileReader
import javax.script._

object DemoApp extends App {
    val engine: ScriptEngine with Compilable with javax.script.Invocable  = new ScriptEngineManager()
    .getEngineByName("scala")
    .asInstanceOf[ScriptEngine with javax.script.Invocable with Compilable]
    val reader = new FileReader("src/main/scala/Demo.sc")
    engine.compile(reader).eval()
    val result = engine.invokeFunction("fun")
}
```

below is the Demo.sc

```
def fun: String = {
"Rerutn from Fun"
}
```

Below is the exception at runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Scripted cannot be cast to javax.script.Invocable
at DemoApp$.delayedEndpoint$DemoApp$1(DemoApp.scala:13)
at DemoApp$delayedInit$body.apply(DemoApp.scala:5)
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
at DemoApp$.main(DemoApp.scala:5)
at DemoApp.main(DemoApp.scala)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the *Scala* script engine implements `Compilable`, but not `Invocable`, which is why you're getting a cast exception.

In any case, when you call `eval` on the result of the compilation, your code is executed, so you don't need to invoke anything via `Invocable`.

Using `asInstanceOf` is a little frowned-upon, so the following is more idiomatic.

Try this:

```scala
import java.io.FileReader
import javax.script._

object DemoApp extends App {
  // Get the Scala engine.
  val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")

  // See if the engine supports compilation.
  val compilerEngine = engine match {
    case c: Compilable => Some(c)
    case _ => None
  }

  // If the engine supports compilation, compile and run the program.
  val result = compilerEngine.map {ce =>
    val reader = new FileReader("src/main/scala/Demo.sc")
    ce.compile(reader).eval()
  }

  println(result.fold("Script not compilable")(_.toString))
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want to get your original code working, you should so this:

```scala
import java.io.FileReader
import javax.script._

object DemoApp extends App {
  val engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
    .getEngineByName("scala")
    .asInstanceOf[ScriptEngine with Compilable]
  val reader = new FileReader("src/main/scala/Demo.sc")
  val result = engine.compile(reader).eval()
  // Output the result
  println(result.toString)
}
```

Comment: how to call /eval a function from the compile script by passing argument

Comment: @JaganArikuti I don't think it's possible if you use the _Scala_ script engine, since it doesn't implement `Invocable`. If you use the _nashorn_ script engine - which processes _JavaScript_ scripts instead of _Scala_ - then you can both compile _JavaScript_ scripts as well as invoke methods defined by them. With the _Scala_ script engine, all you can do is interpret _Scala_ scripts, or compile them and evaluate the result.

Answer (score 1):

workaround using actor in scripts  -

Main application Demo

```
class SampleActor extends Actor {
    implicit val log = Logging(context.system, this)
    def fun() = {
        val settings: Settings = new Settings
        settings.sourcepath.value = "src/main/scripts"
        settings.usejavacp.value = true
        settings.dependencyfile.value = "*.scala"
        val engine: Scripted = Scripted(new Scripted.Factory, settings)
        engine.getContext.setAttribute("context0",context,ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE)

        val reader = new FileReader("src/main/scripts/ActorScript.scala")
        engine.eval("import akka.actor.ActorContext \n" +"val context1 = context0.asInstanceOf[ActorContext]")

        val compiledScript : CompiledScript = engine.compile(reader)
        val x = compiledScript.eval()
        x.asInstanceOf[ActorRef] ! "Arikuti"
        x.asInstanceOf[ActorRef] !  1
    }
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case x : String =>
          log.info("Receveid  from ScriptEngine: " +  x)
        case i : Int =>
          log.info("Receveid from ScriptEngine : " +  i)
    }

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
        super.preStart()
        fun()
      }
    }

object ActorDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val system = ActorSystem("clientAdapter")
  val x = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SampleActor]),"Main")
}
}
```

And below 3 scrips are i placed in src/main/scripts

ActorScript.scala

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}
import akka.event.Logging


class ActorScript extends Actor {
implicit val log = Logging(context.system, this)

override def receive = {
case y : Int   =>
  log.info("Recevied from Main Int : " +  y.toString )
  log.info(Convert.fun())
  sender.tell(2,self)
case x : String =>
  log.info("Recevied from Main String " + x)
  log.info(Second.fun())
  sender.tell("Arikuti",self)
}
}

object ActorScript {
  def apply: ActorRef = {
    context1.actorOf(Props(new ActorScript),"ScriptActor")
  }
}

ActorScript.apply
```

Convert.scala

```
object Convert {
  def fun(): String = {
    "I am from Converter:: fun"
  }
}
```

Second.scala

```
object Second {
  def fun(): String = {
    "I am from Second::fun"
  }
}
```

In build.sbt

```
excludeFilter in unmanagedSourceDirectories :=  "src/main/scripts/*.scala"
```

now from Application i can send message to compiled script actor and recevied processed values form the Scripipts